# My list in swift ui is merging the first word from the second group to all the views in my first group

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
struct SportsView: View {
   var body: some View {
       List {
           Group{
               Button(action: {}) {
                   Text("Football/Soccer")
               }
               Button(action: {}) {
                   Text("Basketball")
               }
               Button(action: {}) {
                   Text("Cricket")
               }
               Button(action: {}) {
                   Text("Tennis")
               }
               Button(action: {}) {
                   Text("Swimming")
               }
               Button(action: {}) {
                   Text("American Football")
               }
               Button(action: {}) {
                   Text("Rugby")
               }
               Button(action: {}) {
                   Text("Golf")
               }
               Button(action: {}) {
                   Text("Track & Field")
               }
               Button(action: {}) {
                   Text("Volleyball")
               }
           }
           Group{
               Button(action: {}) {
                   Text("Boxing")
               }
               Button(action: {}) {
                   Text("Sailing")
               }
               Button(action: {}) {
                   Text("Handball")
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

[image: This is the result of my code]

> I wanted to make a list with more than 10 views so what I did is I grouped them but now the first view of the second group is being merged with all the views in the first group.
> I've tried putting the view in a stack but still no change is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem but why not create an array of your sports and create the buttons in a loop

```
private let sports = [
    "Football/Soccer",
    "Basketball",
    "Cricket",
    "Tennis",
    "Swimming",
    "American Football",
    "Rugby",
    "Golf",
    "Track & Field",
    "Volleyball",
    "Boxing",
    "Sailing",
    "Handball"
]

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(sports, id: \.self) { sport in
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text(sport)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}